How to fine-tune with unsloth using multiple GPUs as I'm getting out-of-memory error after running os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]
I was trying to fine-tune Llama 70b on 4 GPUs using unsloth.
I was able to bypass the multiple GPUs detection by coda by running this command. It only detects 1 GPUs.
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]="0"
However, when I was try to run fine-tune, the "trainer_starts = trainer.train()" threw CUDA out of memory error.
It was taking only GPU 0 into the memory estimation -> which is not enough for the fine-tuning.
How can we by pass this?
Or is there another trick for this?
I tried ran the above codes that I shared earlier, and still not able to resolve the error.
Looking into other posts but not been able to find the answer yet.
